# Regarding PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl

Could anybody let me know, if I understand the curl_getinfo() information right?

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://www.someserver.com
    [content_type] => text/html
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 350
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 19
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.078
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0.016
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.031
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.078
    [redirect_time] => 0
)
```

As I understand `pretransfer_time` means the time, when the headers request is already sent to the server and server is executing request? Then the `starttransfer_time` should mean the time, when the page is prepared by the server, and the client starts to receive data (headers+body?). Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About `pretransfer_time`, sure. `starttransfer_time` - when the client starts to receive data, but not server load time. There's no way to know unless it is configurated to send that info somehow.

Answer (score 2):

[**Pretransfer_time**](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html#CURLINFOPRETRANSFERTIME)

> Pass a pointer to a double to receive
>   the time, in seconds, it took from the
>   start until the file transfer is just
>   about to begin. This includes all
>   pre-transfer commands and negotiations
>   that are specific to the particular
>   protocol(s) involved

[**Starttransfer_time**](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html#CURLINFOSTARTTRANSFERTIME)

> Pass a pointer to a double to receive
>   the time, in seconds, it took from the
>   start until the first byte is just
>   about to be transferred. This includes
>   CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME and also the
>   time the server needs to calculate the
>   result